# To get value of textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I dont know why my script is not working. I tried to get value of textbox in javascript but its not giving me a value. Value is shown as null.

```
//This is the code for my textbox

    <td> <input id="demo3" type="text" size="25" runat="server"/><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo3','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)">
     <img src="Resources/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>   </td>

//This is how I trid to access textbox
    exDateTime = document.getElementById('pCtrl').value;
```

but exDateTime is remains null.
I tried using other ways too, but nothing seen happening..

Comment: What version of the .net framework are you using. Your `runat="server"` will (I think) result in a different id being generated. What is the id in the produced HTML?

Comment: The fact that you're using .NET may be relevant. I'd recommend addding `.net` (and perhaps `asp.net`) as tags to your question; if the problem is a .NET issue, then people more experienced with .NET will find your question easier and can help you solve it.

Comment: Please also change `<a href="javascript:NewCal('demo3','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)">` to `<a href="#" onclick="NewCal('demo3','ddmmmyyyy',true,24); return false">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are referring to the proper id.
Try `document.getElementById("demo3").value`

Or atleast paste the code where your "pCtrl" form field is.

**EDIT :** Make sure you set the value for the text box in html or using Javascript for example:

```
<input type='text' id='demo3' value='3'>
```

and then use `document.getElementById("demo3").value` to get the value, otherwise use javascript to assign the value and obtain the value at a later stage using the same.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: @Chirag You want to get the value present in the textbox having the id "demo3" is it?

Comment: @K M G Yes. I want to do the same, but actually problem is something different. I tried to get value of calender to that textbox and then want to get, but problem is textbox is not getting filled.

Comment: @K A G.Now its working without any changes. actually the problems with somewhere else..

Comment: @Chirag Where was the problem then?

Comment: @K A G... Actually the textbox is getting field by some other function. The problems was in that function. Earlier is was not filling the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I bet this is a .net issue

Try this:

```
<input id="demo3" type="text" size="25" runat="server"/><a 
href="#" onclick="NewCal('<%= demo3.ClientID %>','ddmmmyyyy',true,24); 
return false"><img src="Resources/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" 
alt="Pick a date"></a>   


exDateTime = document.getElementById('<%= demo3.ClientID %>').value;
```