# Compare input values in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a `<input type="text" name="value"/>` in  a loop.

```
 <%for (i=0;i<10;i++){%>
 <input type="text" name="value"/>
 <%}%>
 <input type="button" name="submit">
```

On submit I need to check the input variables(10 boxes) should not exceed the value of 100.

Please let me know how to call a JS and send these 10 values to it and compare the sum with 100.

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with? [How to get a reference to the DOM elements?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction#How_Do_I_Access_the_DOM.3F) [How to access their value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069146/to-get-value-of-textbox-in-javascript)? [How to compare two numbers?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a proper JavaScript answer:

Get a reference to your form:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formId');
```

Bind an event handler for the submit event, e.g.:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {...};
```

Inside the handle, get a reference to all input elements with name `value`:

```
var inputs = this.elements['value'];
```

Iterate over the elements and sum their values:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    sum += +inputs[i].value;
}
```

Stop the default action if the sum is larger than 100:

```
if(sum > 100) {
    return false;
}
```

---

Complete example:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formId');

form.onsubmit = function() {
    var inputs = this.elements['value'],
        sum = 0, i, len;

    for(i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        sum += +inputs[i].value;
    }

    if(sum > 100) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in a div for scope's sake

```
<div id="inputs">
  // Your code
</div>
```

Then you can loop

```
total = 0;
$("#inputs input").each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
alert("You have a total value of" + total);
if(total > 100){
  alert("It's more than 100, I should do something here");
}
```

Comment: @FelixKling if he's using js, he can use jQuery. It's never a bad thing to add it to a project, and if he can't use jQuery he'll make a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @marcgg's answer:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
   total = 0;
   $("#inputs input").each(function(){
     total += parseInt($(this).val());
   });
   alert("You have a total value of" + total);
   if(total > 100){
     alert("It's more than 100, I should do something here");
     return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: imho `e.preventDefault()` would be better than `return false`